# how to use absolute function with percentage in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH b1
     AS (  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Sales) AS cnt,
                  TO_CHAR (Date, 'YYYY-MON') AS Period
             FROM orders
            WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE '2020-02-01' AND DATE '2020-02-29'
         GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Date, 'YYYY-MON')
         UNION ALL
           SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Sales) AS cnt,
                  TO_CHAR (Date, 'YYYY-MON') AS Period
             FROM orders
            WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE '2020-03-01' AND DATE '2020-03-31'
         GROUP BY TO_CHAR (Date, 'YYYY-MON'))
  SELECT cnt,
         Period,
         CASE
            WHEN ROUND (
                      ABS (cnt - LAG (cnt, 1, cnt) OVER (ORDER BY period DESC))
                    / cnt
                    * 100,
                    2) < 0
            THEN
                  ROUND (
                       (cnt - LAG (cnt, 1, cnt) OVER (ORDER BY period DESC))
                     / cnt
                     * 100,
                     2)
               || '%'
               || '  (Increase) '
            WHEN ROUND (
                      (cnt - LAG (cnt, 1, cnt) OVER (ORDER BY period DESC))
                    / cnt
                    * 100,
                    2) > 0
            THEN
                  ROUND (
                       (cnt - LAG (cnt, 1, cnt) OVER (ORDER BY period DESC))
                     / cnt
                     * 100,
                     2)
               || '%'
               || '  (Decrease) '
         END
            AS variances
    FROM b1
ORDER BY Period;
```

Comment: Apart from posting some code, what is the problem?

Comment: suppose i am getting -90% in variance but i need only 90,... mean i need absolute % in variance column

Comment: For a start, don't do presentation layer formatting in your data layer.  If you do that in your application/report/whatever, you won't need to repeat the calculation four times in this code, and will be able to re-use this code at a later stage (because the values will be numeric, rather than text).

Comment: need absolute %
example :- 
if my variance value is +ve then value should be like (90 %    decrease) like as if variance value is -ve then value should be like (90 %    increase)

Comment: Secondly, you have `CASE WHEN ABS(x) < 0 THEN x WHEN x > 0 THEN x`; which is just a typo, because `ABS(x)` is never less than 0, and you never use `ABS()` in your `THEN` blocks.

Comment: Finally, by converting your dates to strings with `MON` in the formatting, and then ordering by that string in your `LAG()`; you're going to get the months in the wrong order; `'2020-Feb'` will be before `'2020-Jan'` because `'F'` is before `'J'` - use real date data-types.

Comment: in my code where i can put abs??

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert dates to strings to round them.  Especially if you're going to order by that string.  You do Not want `'2020-Feb'` coming before `'2020-Jan'`...

Secondly you have `ABS()` in the 'WHEN' part of your `CASE` expression, but you need it in the `THEN` part...

```
CASE WHEN ABS(x) < 0  -- This is what you have, which is NEVER true
```

Thirdly, your CTE doesn't need to UNION two sets of data together, you just need a single WHERE clause...

Finally, don't repeat your code multiple times, use CTEs or other patterns to write it just once...

```
WITH
    b1 AS
(
        -- Using ROUND and avoiding UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Sales) AS cnt,
           ROUND(Date, 'MONTH') AS Period
      FROM orders
     WHERE Date >= DATE '2020-02-01'
       AND Date <  DATE '2020-04-01'
  GROUP BY ROUND(Date, 'MONTH')
),
    b2 AS
(
    SELECT cnt,
           Period,
           cnt - LAG (cnt, 1, cnt) OVER (ORDER BY period DESC)  AS delta
      FROM b1
)
SELECT cnt,
       Period,
       ROUND(
          ABS(delta) * 100 / cnt,
          2
       )
          AS variances,
       CASE WHEN delta < 0 THEN 'increase'
                           ELSE 'decrease' END   AS variance_direction
  FROM b2
 ORDER BY Period;
```